# Array Vs Strings JAVA

Tags: java

I'm working on a game that have to compare two arrays of different dimensions, for example A 5x5 and B 3x3.

I need to compare only a 3x3 slice of the A matrix with the B one.
To do that I've translated the B matrix and the subMatrix (3x3) of A in two strings and after I've compared it with the equals method of the string class.

So, I would like to know, in term of performances, if is better to compare using the two arrays or with strings.

I have to compare the two arrays each time that the user clicks on button.

Comment: well, why don't you test how long it takes to convert your array to a string and then compare the strings. v.s. comparing the two arrays? For all you know, your particular jvm may be doing exactly that internally anyways for array comparisons.

Comment: *"I have to compare the two arrays each time that the user clicks on button!"* Then it couldn't matter less. Write the code that's clearest.

Comment: The efficiency of pretty much anything that is done to a 25-element array once per button click does not matter at all.

Comment: Go with array for 2 reasons: 1. It's a lot more clear on what you're doing. 2. You don't have to fiddle with comparing strings, which is hard to debug. Bonus reason 3: 1ms vs 4ms does not matter, at all.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg i'll try, thank you very much. Have a good time! :)

Comment: @MarcB "your particular jvm may be doing exactly that internally anyways for array comparisons" *Really?!* I'm surprised at you spouting such nonsense. Saying to time it is also unhelpful, because (a) someone unfamiliar with writing benchmarks in a JIT'ed language is unlikely to get a meaningful result, and (b) the result alone would not give understanding, which is what is being sought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve performance, the best approach is to do as little as possible.

If you only need to compare the 3x3 of each matrix, I suggest you write a method which compares the common sub-matrix in one go without creating any new data structures.